# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path' on Visual Studio's jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I get the following error when I want to import matplotlib.pyplot on the Visual Studio's jupyter-notebook.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~/miniconda3/envs/firstSteps/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in 
    903 # triggering resolution of _auto_backend_sentinel.
    904 rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
--> 905     cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
    906     # Strip leading comment.
    907     transform=lambda line: line[1:] if line.startswith("#") else line,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in _get_data_path(*args)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

But I don't have this error if I try the same code on the navigator's jupyter-notebook.
So I don't understand why I get this error since both notebook are running under the same kernel which have the matplotlib 3.3.1 version installed on.

I would be grateful if someone can give me any enlightenment. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What solved it for me was closing and then restarting VS Code.
I was installing matplotlib while running VS code and I guess the update wasn't taken into consideration. (Also make sure you're in the right python/conda env)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and solve it by using the following sequence \

- use terminal to direct to project root folder
- Suppose you are running `conda` environment. so, activate the environment by 
  `conda activate env-name`
- run python interpreter : `python` command and check weather matplotib has installed by\
  `import matplotlib`
- run `code .` command to open VScode in this directory.
- open terminal and check weather environment has activated
  [image]
- also check weather jupyter Ipython kernel runs on the same environment
  [image]
- if any environment is not the one then, change it to a particular one\

this won't happen in the `pip` environment usually, because VScode does not activate two **channels** [*pip*, *conda*] or conda environment automatically most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was using the wrong python kernel. I had that problem when using the standard python kernel, but not when using a virtual env (which is what I usually use).

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit or a comment.

Comment: I know, but I do not have a reputation to comment, and it might provide some insight as I found this question because I had the same problem and solved it this way.

Comment: If you could explain a bit more it might be more helpful

Comment: I had that error when using a kernel, which was not up-to-date (but in which I had already used matplotlib a few months/a year ago). When I used one that it was up-to-date, the problem disappear. (This is not an actual solution, but it solved the problem for me and may be an hint for someone else).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I tried to import matplotlib from a directory containing a file `org.py` that also tried to load matplotlib. Apparently that overruled an import somewhere inside matplotlib.

I had a file `org.py`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

and then in the same directory just ran

```
$ python
>>> import matplotlib
```

to get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    import pprint
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/pprint.py", line 38, in <module>
    import dataclasses as _dataclasses
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/dataclasses.py", line 3, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/copy.py", line 60, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "/home/michael/org.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 52, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, collections, cm, colors, contour, ticker
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import (_api, _path, artist, cbook, cm, colors as mcolors, _docstring,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .colors import BoundaryNorm
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 43, in <module>
    import defusedxml.ElementTree as ElementTree
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/defusedxml/ElementTree.py", line 12, in <module>
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 2074, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

while having

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

inside a script resulted in

```
  File "/home/michael/./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 890, in <module>
    cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 559, in _get_data_path
    return Path(matplotlib.get_data_path(), *args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

The bottom line here is that this error can be a total red herring. There was nothing wrong with matplotlib or a virtualenv or anything like that. No (re)installation was needed. Instead, some imports were seeing local files instead of library modules (in this case `from org.python.core import PyStringMap` was redirected to a local script).