# matplotlib.pyplot has no attribute 'get_data_path'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know there is an answer to a similar question like this, but it won't help in my particular case. I wrote some python code for a client, and he can't get it to run in windows CMD. He has an error with matplotlib. The error is with the line "`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`" and it says that matplotlib has no attribute '`get_data_path`'. He isn't using conda or anything, just writing '`py program.py`' to run the code. I've included a picture he sent me. Does anyone know what to do about this.

Screenshot showing issue:
[image]

Comment: Did you check [AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826975/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-get-data-path-on-visual-s)? Did you try removing matplotlib and installing it again (preferably the latest version)? `pip uninstall matplotlib`? `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`?

Comment: I checked that, but it only had information for running in conda or other environments, not plain CMD. I'll try the reinstall thing though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up figuring it out though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you figured it out? because I have similar problem and I could not solve it. and all other posts regarding this issue did not help me. @JosephWalker

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried all the above

```
pip uninstall matplotlib

pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

I also tried

```
pip install matplotlib --user
```

Nothing worked so finally I created a new env and it worked only with the new env.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I am installing Matplotlib in my new environment in Anaconda, at the same line: `"import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"`.

What I did to fix is to restart the jupyter kernel and re-run the code twice (1st time failed, second time passed), after I complete the matplotlib installation in anaconda prompt (with command: `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`, then fixed the issue "DLL load failed while importing _imaging" with `conda update Pillow`).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in Jupyter Notebook.
Restarting the kernel made it work.