# Can't import matplotlib in Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to import Matplotlib for my Python app but I either get this error for mpl versions 3.4.0+

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

or this

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dedent' from 'matplotlib.cbook' (E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py)
```

for older versions.

I don't want to install another version of python because I am afraid that everything that worked so far will break.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get\_data\_path' on Visual Studio's jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826975/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-get-data-path-on-visual-s)

Comment: If you are using Anaconda and are in need of different versions of python and packages, you can create virtual  environment for those projects.

Comment: I had no idea about the virtual anaconda so thank you I will give it a try.