# problems in pip install and matplotlib library installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

to install matplotlib library its recomended uses this base:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

when I execute the following code:

`(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install -U pip`

results in this warning:

```
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
 Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (22.0.4)
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
 WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

so with `-U matplotlib` do:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.29.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

and lastly, when I execute `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` resuts in:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-310f65eff20b> in <module>
      1 import networkx as nx
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import pandas as pd

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    875 # triggering resolution of _auto_backend_sentinel.
    876 rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
--> 877     cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
    878     # Strip leading comment.
    879     transform=lambda line: line[1:] if line.startswith("#") else line,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in _get_data_path(*args)
    478     return a file object, otherwise just a file path.
    479 
--> 480     Sample data files are stored in the 'mpl-data/sample_data' directory within
    481     the Matplotlib package.
    482 

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

I don't know what to do, hope you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826975/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-get-data-path-on-visual-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826975/attributeerror-module-matplotlib-has-no-attribute-get-data-path-on-visual-s) ? It "smells" like your matplotlib has not installed properly or else your environments are confused somehow.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll delete this question in case of duplicate

Comment: Only delete if the other answer answers your question! Otherwise add enough information to differentiate your question from that other one and there will hopefully be a fix proposed.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the location in the warning and look for folders starting with "**~**", if you find any, delete them and rerun the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deleting the folders starting with '~' helped. Thank you very much! I did the upgrade of version and after that started to show the warning. The folders with '~' had previous version number in name. So I believe there was some confusion, as described above in comment from @Pam.

Comment: (kill the python process that handle them first)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have installed it incorrectly. Try executing

```
pip show matplotlib
```

Does it show the version installed?

If you are using anaconda, it should be installed through

```
conda install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (i.e., cmd) and go to the problematic folder, in your case `c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages` but on my computer `c:\python310\lib\site-packages`.
Then remove all the directories starting with `~`, in my case:

```
~ip
~ip-22.1.2.dist-info
```

using the command from [here](https://superuser.com/a/764352/588662):

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /s /b ~*') do rd /s /q %i
```

then try upgrading pip again to be sure things are OK now:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

---

interestingly enough, I had the same issue on my macOS device as well on the `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, and the problematic folders being

```
~BB
~BB-0.2-py3.10.egg-info
```

I could easily remove them by going to the said folder and running

```
rm -rf ~*
```

Answer (score -1):

Whether you encounter this problem when trying to install matplotlib or sqlalchemy the fix is simple and the same.

Try locating the folder it returns, (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)  and delete any  folder starting with ~

Comment: How does this answer differ from the answer already posted here?