# I am getting the error below while importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
File c:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:877, in <module>
    870     return config
    873 # When constructing the global instances, we need to perform certain updates
    874 # by explicitly calling the superclass (dict.update, dict.items) to avoid
    875 # triggering resolution of _auto_backend_sentinel.
    876 rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
--> 877     cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
    878     # Strip leading comment.
    879     transform=lambda line: line[1:] if line.startswith("#") else line,
    880     fail_on_error=True)
    881 dict.update(rcParamsDefault, rcsetup._hardcoded_defaults)
    882 # Normally, the default matplotlibrc file contains *no* entry for backend (the
    883 # corresponding line starts with ##, not #; we fill on _auto_backend_sentinel
    884 # in that case.  However, packagers can set a different default backend
    885 # (resulting in a normal `#backend: foo` line) in which case we should *not*
    886 # fill in _auto_backend_sentinel.

File c:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py:518, in _get_data_path(*args)
    512 def _get_data_path(*args):
    513     """
    221     return props[name].__get__(instance)
--> 222 raise AttributeError(
    223     f"module {cls.__module__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

Comment: [Others have had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63826975/1609514) but no clear answer was found. It might be something to do with your environment setup or IDE. B.t.w. why is your Python installed on the desktop on your OneDrive?  Shouldn't it be installed in the local files on your machine? (Sorry, I'm not familiar with PC installation).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a virtual environment, it should ideally work there.